# Когда использую поиск в WP то везде выводит результат, а если нахожусь на single.php то ничего не происходит, почему?

Tags: php, wordpress, поиск

Вот код search.php. Как сделать что бы находясь на сингл(открытой статье) я мог искать что то в поиске (поиск находится в сайтбаре)? Если переключаюсь на стандартные теми то поиск на сингл работает. Искал в коде отличия, не могу понять что у меня не так с кодом.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main>
<div class="container index">
    <section class="posts">
        <div class="innerwrap-posts">

<h4><?php echo 'Результат поиска: ' . '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>'; ?></h4>
          <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $postcounter = $postcounter + 1; $wp_query->the_post();?>

          <article>

              <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
              <div class="images">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full') ?>
                    <?php the_content() ?>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="overwrap-info">
                  <div class="head">
                    <?php the_category(', ' ); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="overwrap-views">

<span class="views"><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></span>

                      <div class="comments"><a href="">25</a></div>
                  </div>
              </div>

          </article>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
else :
echo '<p class="nothing-found">Извините, по Вашему запросу ничего не найдено</p>';
endif;
?>

        </div>


          <?php wp_pagenavi();  ?>

    </section>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
 </main>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Переменная `$wp_query` у вас задана? Или объявите ее глобальной, или попробуйте `if (have_posts())`, как в стандартной теме.

Comment: Копировал с стандартной темы и обернул (have_posts()) в $wp_query, не помогло. Если беру код с теми где поиск работает в сингл, и он все равно не работает, может дело не в файле  search.php? Ни как не могу решить эту проблему. Может есть где-то готовый вариант?